# Why does Cloudflare's 1.1.1.1 allow you to bypass MAC filltering?

Tags: vpn, mac-address, cloudflare

I was trying Virgin Media's MAC filtering, and set it to not allow my laptop to use the internet at 5:00PM as a test.

I was at the time using cloudflare's VPN 1.1.1.1 with Warp, and once it hit 5PM, it simply just allowed me to continue to use the internet. If I turned this VPN off, I could no longer connect to anything online, and it did not allow me to turn the VPN back on until after 5. If I tried using 1.1.1.1 DNS mode, it turned off as soon as it hit 5:00pm.

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Is that MAC filtering implemented on the router or through some settings on VM's website? If the former, did you reboot the router - even if it didn't prompt you to do so?

Comment: Through VM's settings

Comment: It did work on other devices, just not the one with 1.1.1.1 on. Works on phone too, if I installed the 1.1.1.1 app. Is this the wrong place to ask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of home gateways run Linux and use the 'iptables' firewall. Most likely the MAC-based filtering is implemented as the same kind of 'iptables' firewall rules as normal TCP/UDP filtering – and what they both have in common is that in most typical setups, they're only applied to the *initial* packet of each connection.

Most firewalls are *stateful* and remember all individual packet "flows" they see (be it TCP connections or UDP streams), meaning they will only check the initial packet of a flow against rules, but all further packets will be immediately accepted. Among other things, this is necessary to make NAT work (the router has to remember how to un-NAT packets going in the other direction), but it is also used by regular firewall rules – very often, the *first* rule in iptables rulesets is "accept if packet belongs to an established connection".

For example, if your firewall allowed e.g. inbound SSH connections on port 22, then you deleted that rule (or indeed even if you added a *deny* rule for port 22) while one such inbound SSH connection *was still active,* the high-priority "allow established" rule would still keep allowing that connection until it was closed. Similarly, an outbound VPN tunnel is seen as a single continuous flow; as long as you stay connected to the VPN server, even if the VPN port is blocked later, the stateful firewall may continue allowing that connection through.

So I strongly suspect that your MAC-based filtering is implemented in exactly the same way, with the rules having the same priorities. That is, I suspect that your router still starts with an "allow established" rule that accepts every *already active* connection no matter where it's from, and only then you have "allow from <list of MACs>" rules that implement the filtering.

<sub>(Now there's nothing in iptables that would mandate the "allow established" to be the very first – it is certainly possible to add "immediate deny" rules before it – but the point here isn't about what can be done in theory, it's about how it was most likely done in your router in practice.</sub>

<sub>Similarly, it is certainly possible to "kick" connections out of iptables' flow cache and force them to be re-evaluated against the rules, but this is usually not done because it's difficult to guess in an automated way which flows *should* be removed – and just clearing it all out would cause unnecessary interruptions to *everyone's* connections through the router, especially because the same cache also keeps track of NAT mappings for each connection.)</sub>

Answer (score -1):

The explanation must be connected to the MAC address you used to filter,
as you probably used the MAC address of the network adapter of your
computer.

However, a VPN works by creating a virtual network adapter that has
*a different MAC address from your adapter*.
The connections initiated by the VPN come still via your host's
adapter, but the MAC address is spoofed to seem like this is
coming from another computer.

That's why the filter did not detect connections coming from the virtual
adapter as being related to the filter.

When you turned the VPN off, any attempt to turn it on requires
an initial connection to the Cloudflare servers via the host adapter,
which the filter did not permit. So you couldn't connect again
to the VPN as long as the filter was active.

Comment: It really doesn't work that way. Packets sent through the virtual VPN interface do not go directly on the wire – the whole point of a VPN is that they're tunnelled *inside* the original VPN connection; the virtual IP and MAC headers are both in the encrypted payload and remain "invisible" to the physical network.

Comment: @user1686: Disagree. If the packet was marked with the MAC address of the host as the source, it wouldn't be allowed through. In other words, if, as you say, the MAC address of the virtual adapter was invisible to the filter, why didn't it block the package? After all, the package needed to have *some* MAC address as the source, and in that case the only one possible would be that of the host.

Comment: Thanks! That cleared things up a lot

Comment: “The connections initiated by the VPN come still via your host's adapter, but the MAC address is spoofed to seem like this is coming from another computer.”—No, that’s not how a VPN works. The tunnel MAC address (if any!) is only visible _inside_ the tunnel, which is encrypted.

Comment: @DanielB: The tunnel is encrypted, but the MAC address of the originating adapter is not and can't be. Otherwise, the virtual adapter wouldn't know which answering packets were destined to it, and the router wouldn't have any address for sending the answering packets. In simple Ethernet, packets are sent over the wire, and each communicant handles its own based on whether the destination MAC address in the packet header is its own. Otherwise, the VPN would need to integrate itself into the host network driver, no need for a virtual adapter, which is a too complicated architecture to implement.

Comment: @harrymc: The virtual adapter doesn't need to "know" which packets are destined to it, because it's not attached to any physical Ethernet in the first place. All packets the OS "sends" through that adapter are consumed by the VPN software that controls the interface (which then sends out an encrypted packet to your router using your regular Ethernet MAC); all packets "received" from that adapter were produced out of thin air by the VPN software. That's how TAP adapters work in Windows, it's how `tun` adapters work on Linux.

Comment: @harrymc: As far as the physical Ethernet communication goes, the VPN looks like a normal UDP/IP packet flow between you and the VPN server, using your regular LAN IP address and your regular MAC address. (It's occassionally TCP, but more often UDP.) The received "answer" packets are routed to the VPN software according to their UDP port (much like any UDP-using software), which consumes the packet, decrypts it to find the nested VPN IP packet within, pushes _that_ through the virtual network adapter to be "received" again by the OS.

Comment: @user1686: When packets are routed, IP addresses are used to determine the next hop and the physical/MAC address is used to physically identify the interface serving as the next hop. If the MAC address of the virtual adapter isn't visible, it won't receive the packet or be able at all to communicate over the network. What you say is also empirically not supported by poster's experience where a *MAC filter* fails to block the VPN.

Comment: @harrymc: The virtual interface _isn't_ the next hop for inbound packets; the physical interface is. The virtual interface "receives" packets whenever the VPN software decides that it should receive packets, it's an isolated link that has no direct relationship with any other network.

Comment: @user1686: Yes, the VPN driver sniffs packets over the host's adapter - there is only one physical adapter. The host driver doesn't further handle these packets, the VPN driver does. In the simplest case, the host driver doesn't need to know about the existence of the VPN or to serve it, just to give it the hooks for it to serve itself.  (I'm not trying to deal here with flavors of VPN which may do things differently.)

Comment: @harrymc The VPN client establishes a _regular_ TCP or UDP connection to the VPN server. That’s the tunnel. What happens inside is entirely irrelevant to the handling of the VPN connection itself. There is no packet sniffing or MAC address spoofing. It’s just a network connection like any other.

Comment: @DanielB: In this case the virtual adapter becomes irrelevant. I wonder if the whole discussion above is really about the architectural differences between Windows and Linux. Windows doesn't have anything like the flexible iptables of Linux and its more limited implementation requires simpler solutions for VPN drivers (and for VM products).

Comment: @harrymc Exactly! The virtual adapter is entirely irrelevant _outside the system_. This is how VPN works on _every_ platform. It is also unrelated to IPTables (most of which could in fact be easily replicated using Windows Filtering Platform). Strictly speaking, there are no _VPN drivers_ either. Only drivers for virtual network interfaces, sometimes. The VPN client is a regular application like your internet browser.

Comment: @DanielB: In Windows every adapter, virtual or not, needs an *installed* driver, meaning not a regular application. The VPN client itself is only a front-end to that driver, so is truly a regular application. I think perhaps we're arguing about implementation details from differing personal experiences.